# HttpContext.User is empty while the Jwt has the values sent

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, authorization, httpcontext

I am trying to implement Authentication with Jwt. And also Authorization using MediatR pipelines. I have created a Pipeline named AuthorizationBehavior which looks for a spesified claims in the claims of the user. If user does not have this claim simply throws an Exception.

```
public class AuthorizationBehavior<TRequest,TResponse> :IPipelineBehavior<TRequest,TResponse> where TRequest : IRequest<TResponse>, 
IAuthorizableRequest
{
private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor;

public AuthorizationBehavior(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)
{
    _contextAccessor = contextAccessor;
}

public async Task<TResponse> Handle(TRequest request, RequestHandlerDelegate<TResponse> next, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    
    List<string>? userRoles = _contextAccessor.HttpContext.User.GetRoles();

    if (!request.RequiredRoles.Any(requiredRole => userRoles.Contains(requiredRole)))
        throw new AuthorizationException("You are not authorized for this operation.");
    TResponse response = await next();
    return response;
}
```

}

However when request reaches there, the HttpContext is empty. And HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is false.

Also my program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddServices(builder.Configuration);
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

#region authentication
TokenOptions tokenOptions = 
 builder.Configuration.GetSection("TokenOptions").Get<TokenOptions>();


 builder.Services
   .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
   .AddJwtBearer(options =>
   {
      options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
   {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidIssuer = tokenOptions.Issuer,
        ValidAudience = tokenOptions.Audience,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = SecurityKeyHelper.CreateSecurityKey(tokenOptions.SecurityKey)
        };
   });

   builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
   builder.Services.AddCors(
   opt =>
       opt.AddDefaultPolicy(p =>
       {
           p.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader();
       })
);
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(opt =>
{
    opt.AddSecurityDefinition(
        name: "Bearer",
         securityScheme: new OpenApiSecurityScheme
        {
            Name = "Authorization",
            Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
            Scheme = "Bearer",
            BearerFormat = "JWT",
            In = ParameterLocation.Header,
            Description =
                "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. Example: 
\"Authorization: Bearer YOUR_TOKEN\". \r\n\r\n"
                + "`Enter your token in the text input below.`"
        }
    );
    opt.OperationFilter<BearerSecurityRequirementOperationFilter>();
});


#endregion

// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
 builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddOptions();


var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

W